# How do i make my paths not dependent on who executes the code?

Tags: python, directory, path

I am currently writing a code with python, in which I need to safe some files in a certain path:

r"/Users/nik/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/Projektmodul/Tool/Bausteine/combined.mdl"

Now I want to make is lets say "variable", so that it doesnt matter who executes the code.

Right now if someone else executes the code, it wont work, because is has my name in it.

If I use it on windows, this would be the correct path:
r"\Mac\Dropbox\Projektmodul\Tool\Bausteine\combined.mdl"

How do I get rid of the "Mac" etc.

All in all, I want to make the code more independent.

I know that the name problem can be solved with somethin like:

os.getlogin.

Is this the best way?

Comment: is your code's file placed within `Projektmodul` folder?

Comment: if it is - all you need to do is to use just this path 'Tool/Bausteine/combined.mdl' without anything else at the start of it